# How to display details from profile page to a new page in angularjs using services?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying for a welcome page which displays the users details which he filled in a previous profile page with the message welcome {{name}}. How can i do so with services?

I have created profile.html, profileController.js and welcomePage.html and welcomePageController.js but have difficulty in using the services to transfer details from profile.html to welcomePage.html.

profile.html

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<div>
<form>First Name: &nbsp; <span style="color:red">*</span> <input type="text"><br>
<br>
Last Name: &nbsp; <span style="color:red">*</span>&nbsp; <input type="text"><br>
<br>
Age:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="color:red">*</span> <input type="number"><br>
<br>
Gender:<input type="radio" value="female">Female <input type="radio" value="male">Male
<br>
<br>
<input type="button" value="Submit"> </form>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

welcomePage.html

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=us-ascii">
</head>
<body>
<div>
<h1>Welcome {{user.name}} </h1>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

How to show the details filled in profile.html to welcomePage.html?

How can I do it without using a n sql daabase?

Answer (score 0):

Use below service(this is for less data) and inject the service into your controller.

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.factory('userService', function () {
var list;
var service = {
    setData: setData,
    getData: getData
};
return service;

function setData(item) {
    list = item;
}

function getData() {
    return list;
}
});
```

**To set the data** : userService.setData();

**To get the data** : userService.getData();

**Note**: Use localstorage for large amount of data.